# Running XBMC on Bumblebee-Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, intel-graphics, bumblebee, xbmc

I have XPS 15z with Nvidia GT 525M and Intel graphics cards running using optimus technology.
Currently, when I start xbmc it runs using the "intel" driver. And it runs totally fine but I would like to know if there is a difference when running xbmc on intel or nvidia ?

If yes, how can I run xbmc on nvidia ?! I tried "optirun xbmc" but it became sluggish and unusable.

Comment: if you run: `vblank_mode=0 optirun xbmc` OR `vblank_mode=0 primusrun xbmc` How's that?

Comment: @aXept Could you explain more what the difference does it make running with or without for each command?

Comment: @aXept It works :D ... can u please explain what is "vblank"? and also could you also point out if it will enhance the video quality when xbmc is running using optirun (nvidia card instead of intel)?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run: `vblank_mode=0 optirun xbmc` OR `vblank_mode=0 primusrun xbmc` How's that?

vblank_mode=0 is just for the graphic card not to set a default refresh rate on the screen (monitor/tv). It set the best possible refresh rate. It MAY make tearing because it sets the refresh rate higher then your monitor supports.

For the "optirun" vs "primusrun" I found this information:

*Primus brings better performance and less power consumption when using Bumblebee, by replacing VirtualGL. According to the Bumblebee G+ page, this has the following advantages over the optirun (VirtualGL) solution used by default in Bumblebee:*

*- Less overhead (better framerates) and cleaner solution (no networking or compression involved at all)*

*- Fixes the "bug" that causes Bumblebee to shut down the GPU too early sometimes (no more need for the "optirun bash" workaround)*

*- Less buggy/glitchy, easier to debug*

*- Only uses/starts secondary GPU for OpenGL parts of applications - everything else remains on your main GPU (power savings)*